# assinging to an object from freshly allocated memory

Tags: c++, object, assignment-operator

How standard-compliant is to allocate row memory for an array and then call the assignment operator on the objects from that array?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
void func(size_t sz, size_t pos)
{
static constexpr std::align_val_t __al = std::align_val_t(alignof(T));
T* data= static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sz * sizeof(T), __al));
data[pos] = T(1, 2); //is this legal? thechnically object at data[pos] is in some undetermenistic state.
}
```

Comment: Don't use identifiers that start with two underscores. Those are reserved for the C++ implementation.

Comment: @aschepler — and that’s just a special case of the rule that names **containing** two consecutive underscores are reserved.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's identifiers starting with _one_ underscore then an uppercase letter, or containing two consecutive underscores.

Comment: @aschepler you are right, I misread what https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid only for scalar types (like numeric types or any pointer type), or class types (including unions) that have a ["trivial" default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor), or arrays of such types. If `T` is a class type with non-trivial default constructor or no default constructor, or an array of such class types, it is undefined behavior to call any member function on memory where no object was created, even if that member is a copy assignment operator.

(The current C++20 draft has some changes in [[basic.life]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life) which appear to also exclude the case of a trivial default constructor, but I'm not entirely sure of the implication.)

The correct and safe way to do this is using "placement new":

```
template <typename T>
void func(size_t sz, size_t pos)
{
    static constexpr std::align_val_t al = std::align_val_t(alignof(T));
    std::byte* buffer = static_cast<std::byte*>(::operator new(sz * sizeof(T), al));
    T* data = ::new(static_cast<void*>(buffer + pos*sizeof(T))) T(1, 2);
}
```

The above passes the arguments `1, 2` directly to the constructor of `T` which is invoked by the new-expression. If the example was an oversimplification and you did have some other reason to default-initialize the object (assuming default-initialization is possible) and then reassign it, that's simple too:

```
template <typename T>
void func(size_t sz, size_t pos)
{
    static constexpr std::align_val_t __al = std::align_val_t(alignof(T));
    std::byte* buffer = static_cast<std::byte*>(::operator new(sz * sizeof(T), al));
    T* data = ::new(static_cast<void*>(buffer + pos*sizeof(T))) T(1, 2);
    // Whatever other logic...
    data[pos] = T(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not valid.  `data[pos]` isn't just in some undetermined state.  No `T` object exists at all in the memory pointed to by `data`.  It is therefore not valid to call `T::operator=` on a non-existent object.

You need to use placement `new` in this case:

```
template <typename T>
void func(size_t sz, size_t pos)
{
    static constexpr std::align_val_t __al = std::align_val_t(alignof(T));
    T* data = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sz * sizeof(T), __al));
    T* ptr = new (data + pos) T(1, 2);
}
```

This constructs a new `T` object at the memory address `data + pos`.  You will need to manually call `T`'s destructor to destroy that object before you free the memory you allocated.